# How to downgrade a AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon Web Service EC2 virtual server large type. Now I want to downgrade it to small type. I want to keep the hard disk information but just download the configure of the server. The main reason is to save few bucks. How can I do this?

I think I should:

1. stop the current instance.
2. detach the volume from the current instance.
3. terminate the instance.
4. recreate a new small-type instance from scratch.
5. attach the volume to the small-type instance.

I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do the downgrade or they have some formal way to do it. I tried to look up from the doc but couldn't find anything useful. I think someone here must be able to help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the best way is:

1. Snapshot the volumes from the current instance.
2. Create the new small type instance
3. Use the snapshot(s) to create a replica of your existing volumes.
4. Attach the new volume(s) created to small instance.
5. Test it and switch ElasticIP to the new instance if everything is working ok.

Comment: btw, dont kill yet your current instance unless the small instance is working really well.

Comment: The large server is 64bit Windows 2008 and the small server is 32bit Windows 2008. It seems that I had the problem of connecting to the small server after attaching a volume created from the 64bit server.

Comment: Just make sure when attaching the volume to mount it at /dev/sda1 if you want that to be your root volume

Comment: Can you explain how to create a replica of a snapshot of 50GB EBS to 30GB? It's not allowing me in today's scenario.

Answer (score 105):

I don't know how it worked back then in December 2010. But now it's very simple, maybe Amazon simplified it recently.

Steps

1. Stop the instance
2. Click the Check box next to the instance
3. Click Actions button
4. Choose "Change Instance Type"

That's It!

---

### WARNING: Instance IP will change

Comment: Yes, time-saver for myself, too. Worked great, made a downgrade trivial.

Comment: This should be the best answer ! Cheers

Comment: This does not work for many instance types when downgrading, e.g. when the running instance is an older generation compared to the current options. There are incompatibilities.

Comment: yes @randalv you are right. now that new instances are being added into AWS's pool of instances types, upgrading and downgrading is not possible between few instance types.

Comment: Is there any risk following this option ? Suppose if it fails during transition may be due to old instance type or some other reason, will I be able to get everything running ?

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I need! Time-saver!

Answer (score -4):

1. Stop the instance
2. Click the Check box next to the instance
3. Click Actions button and Choose "Change Instance Type"
4. Start the Instance.
   That's It

Comment: How does this answer differ from the other highly-voted answer posted years ago?